# Using passport.js with yeoman and grunt for authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, yeoman, passport.js

I'm trying to work out how to use passport.js with grunt/yeoman. I have the following:

```
// at the top of my gruntfile.js
var passport = require('passport');
var BasicStrategy = require('passport-http').BasicStrategy;

passport.use(new BasicStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    return done(null, true); // I would expect this to always succeed, but still challenge for credentials
  }
));

// further down in my connect config.
livereload: {
    options: {
        middleware: function (connect) {
            return [
                lrSnippet,
                passport.initialize(),
                passport.authenticate('basic', { session: false }),
                mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
                mountFolder(connect, yeomanConfig.app)
            ];
        }
    }
}
```

On every request the response just contains `unauthorized`. Removing the call to `passport.authenticate` makes the page work, but obviously there's now no authentication. I've tried changing the order of the middleware and that hasn't helped, and I'm nowhere near an expert with yeoman/grunt so I'm not entirely sure what else to try...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sending the authorization header when attempting to authorize?

Comment: @vadim yes, and this all works when not going through passport.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that you need to pass an object to `done()` inside of your `BasicStrategy` callback. As I recall, passport JS uses this object to populate req.user in express apps, and because of this I would think it probably expects an `object` not a `boolean`.

Here is a more robust example of that same function that I use in many apps:

```
  passport.use(new BasicStrategy(
    function(clientID, clientSecret, done) {
      AuthClient.findOne({ clientID: clientID }, function(err, client) {
        if (err) { return done(err); }
        if (!client) { return done(null, false); }
        if (client.secret != clientSecret) { return done(null, false); }
        return done(null, client);
      });
    }
  ));
```

As you can see the BasicStrategy is uses to analyze a a clientID and clientSecret which is the equivalent to your username / password combination. Since you aren't actually pulling it from a db as is shown in my example, I would expect if you just follow the suggestion above and pass `{}` to `done(null, {})`, it might work better.

Comment: Scanning the source, I'm almost positive it doesn't matter what the user object is. The code only verifies to make sure it's truthy, then just sets `req.user` to whatever you passed it.